# Python requests - retry for any status code but not 400

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

I am using the following snippet(please note, only partial snippets shown):

```
from urllib3.util import Retry
status_forcelist = (500, 502, 504)


retry = Retry(
        total=retries,
        read=retries,
        connect=retries,
        backoff_factor=backoff_factor,
        status_forcelist=status_forcelist,
        method_whitelist=frozenset(['GET', 'POST'])
```

As of now, the retry would be done for status codes `500`,`502`,`504`. However, I intend to retry for any status code but not `400`. Is there a graceful way to achieve this instead of populating/hardcoding the `status_forcelist` for all status codes  ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can take the codes from `request` module - which saves you writing them out. In case any new ones get introduced you would have them as well:

```
import requests
from urllib3.util import Retry

status_forcelist = tuple( x for x in requests.status_codes._codes if x != 400)

print(status_forcelist)
```

Output:

```
(100, 101, 102, 103, 122, 200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207, 208, 226, 300, 301, 302, 
 303, 304, 305, 306, 307, 308, 401, 402, 403, 404, 405, 406, 407, 408, 409, 410, 411, 412, 
 413, 414, 415, 416, 417, 418, 421, 422, 423, 424, 425, 426, 428, 429, 431, 444, 449, 450, 
 451, 499, 500, 501, 502, 503, 504, 505, 506, 507, 509, 510, 511)
```

*Caveat*: [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#Unofficial_codes) list "self created" / unofficial statuscodes as well as proprietary ones around 9xx which are not covered by this list though. @zwer solution would cover those as well.

Comment: Why isn't `104 (Connection reset by peer)` in this list?

Comment: @amirA sorry for the late answer, your question escaped me. It is not in it because at the time of answering 104 was not a thing inside `requests.status_codes` in the version `requests` I used. It will only ever reflect the ones that are in it - see the added _Caveat_ remark 2years before your question.

Answer (score 6):

`status_forcelist`, unfortunately, applies as a whitelist only (given the use, it can be called a blacklist, tho) so there are no built-in ways to do it *gracefully*. However, you can override (or monkey-patch if that's your thing) [`urllib3.util.retry.Retry.is_retry()`](http://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/urllib3.util.html#urllib3.util.Retry.is_retry) to treat it as a blacklist, something like:

```
import urllib3.util.retry

class BlacklistRetry(urllib3.util.retry.Retry):

    def is_retry(self, method, status_code, has_retry_after=False):
        if not self._is_method_retryable(method):
            return False

        if self.status_forcelist and status_code not in self.status_forcelist:
            # threat as a blacklist --------------^
            return True

        return (self.total and self.respect_retry_after_header and
                has_retry_after and (status_code in self.RETRY_AFTER_STATUS_CODES))
```

Then use it instead of the original `Retry` and just add `400` to its `status_forcelist`.

Answer (score 4):

[The current accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51701293/5506988) has a bug, it retries for successful http status codes, which means it will unnecessarily retry - if you want proof, you can test this with the code from this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69739940/5506988).

---

You could just follow a similar implementation to [`Response.raise_for_status`](https://cs.github.com/psf/requests/blob/177dd90f18a8f4dc79a7d2049f0a3f4fcc5932a0/requests/models.py#L994).

```py
from urllib3.util import Retry
retry = Retry(
        total=retries,
        read=retries,
        connect=retries,
        backoff_factor=backoff_factor,
        status_forcelist=tuple(range(401, 600)),
        method_whitelist=frozenset(['GET', 'POST'])
```