# How to get log of every retry attempt made by Python Requests Library?

Tags: python, python-requests, urllib3

I'm using following code to implement retry mechanism in python requests.

```
from requests import Session
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
from urllib3.util.retry import Retry

s = Session()
retries = Retry(total=5,
                raise_on_redirect=True, 
                raise_on_status=True,
                backoff_factor=1,
                status_forcelist=[ 500, 502, 503, 504 ])
s.mount('http://', HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retries))
s.mount('https://', HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retries))
response=s.get('https://example.com')
```

It is working perfectly, however all this happens silently.
What I want is to get informed whenever a retry attempt is made and if possible why that retry was happened. I want something like this for every retry attempt.

```
print(Exception.__class__)
print('Retrying after' + x + 'seconds')
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can write your own Class to add logs it should be inherited from the Retry.

```
class LogRetry(Retry):
  """
     Adding extra logs before making a retry request     
  """      
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    logger.info(f'<add your logs here>')
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

retries = LogRetry(<your args>)
```

Comment: Doesn't this just log with the retry object is created? It doesn't actually log the retry.

Comment: @DanDiephouse urllib3 creates new instances of the respective Retry class with the new number of retries left if a retry happens (it's implemented in a recursive fashion) https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/blob/96588e9bf66be564c7437da8b1c2c054bc3142b4/src/urllib3/util/retry.py

Answer (score 3):

*Extremely* hacky but it works, it won't log when a retry isn't issued.

```
class LogOnRetry(Retry):
  
    def __init__(self, *args, __logger: logging.Logger = None,**kwargs):
        self.__logger = kwargs.pop("__logger")
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def new(self, **kw) -> Retry:
        kw["__logger"] = self.__logger
        return super().new(**kw)

    def increment(self, method: str | None = None, url: str | None = None, response: BaseHTTPResponse | None = None, error: Exception | None = None, _pool: ConnectionPool | None = None, _stacktrace: TracebackType | None = None) -> Retry:
        if self.__logger:
            pass
            # log here, get access to url, method and response used.
        return super().increment(method, url, response, error, _pool, _stacktrace)
```

Answer (score -1):

Best option I found was to increase logging for urllib:

```
    'urllib3.util.retry':
    level: DEBUG
    handlers: [console]
    propagate: no
```

Output is:

2023-01-20 09:

```
59:41.018 | DEBUG    | logging:callHandlers:1706 - Starting new HTTP connection (1): x.x.x.x:8001
2023-01-20 09:59:48.263 | DEBUG    | logging:callHandlers:1706 - Incremented Retry for (url='/path/'): LogRetry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)
2023-01-20 09:59:48.264 | WARNING  | logging:callHandlers:1706 - Retrying (LogRetry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x28894bf10>, 'Connection to x.x.x.x timed out. (connect timeout=5)')': /path/
```