# Add verbosity to urllib3 Retry with requests?

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, urllib, urllib3

I am trying to use the urllib3 Retry functionality when scraping a website, but have found that it's not very verbose in the way it lets you know when it's retrying.

My class looks like this:

```
class Session:
    def __init__(self):
        self.session = requests.session()
        retry = Retry(total=10, backoff_factor=1, status_forcelist=[413,429,500,502,503,504])
        adapter = HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retry)
        self.session.mount("http://", adapter)
        self.session.mount("https://", adapter)

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        self.session.__exit__()

    def get(self, url, params={}, headers=None):
        """
        Implements the get function defined below
        """
        return get(url, self.session, params, headers)


def get(url: str, session=None, params=None, headers=None,) -> requests.Response:
    """
    Function to return the response from a request given certain parameters, including auth and session
    """
    logger.info("Get request to url: %s", url)

    if session:
        response = session.get(url, params=params, headers=headers,)
    else:
        response = requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headers,)
    response.raise_for_status()

    return response
```

I want to be able to add some logging, such as:

```
failed on 1st attempt, backing off for 1s...
failed on 2nd attempt, backing off for 2s...
```

etc. Is there any way to do this with the Retry functionality other than writing something bespoke?

Comment: Have you tried [adjusting the log level](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user-guide.html?highlight=log#logging) on urllib3 generally?

Comment: this is a good shout, although it only returns info on the current retry number, rather than the timeout - presumably that means there isn't anything that can be done considering the information doesn't seem to be there at the lowest level of logging?

Comment: you can try [get-log-of-every-attempt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69739940/4628154), and add more custom details you want.